# Accents for characters from R Markdown to Microsoft Word

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, pdflatex

I'm trying to produce a word document with R markdown. Usually i'm creating pdf-files with no problems. I use Latex syntax to create accents for characters for normal text like:

```
$\'{e}\'{e}$n
```

And then it produces "één" correctly when i knit my pdf. But this doesn't seem to work when i knit a word document, it will just show "$\'{e}\'{e}$n". So no good. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Just insert één directly into your document. Windows has a charmap utility that will show you all the characters available.

Comment: I have a mac... i tried that, but then it gave me question marks instead...